# How to print a portion of the String, using Random class, in Java?

Tags: java

My goal is to print a portion (5 characters) from the string, using the Random class.

I have already figured out how to randomly print one character from the string, but my goal is to print 5 characters. My code so far:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Training {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Random random = new Random();

        int i = 5;

        System.out.println(text.charAt(random.nextInt(text.length())));
        System.out.println(text.charAt(random.nextInt(text.length())));
        System.out.println(text.charAt(random.nextInt(text.length())));
    }
}
```

The expected output must be any 5 consecutive characters from the String.
For exapmle:

```
hijkl
cdefg
abcde
```

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to pick a *starting* point from 0 to `text.length() - 5` (exclusive upper bound) and then use substring. See if that's enough of a hint.

Comment: You may find [`random.nextInt(text.length() - 5)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random integer and use it to print a substring of the string:

```
String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
Random random = new Random();

int i = 5;  // define the length of the substring

int index = random.nextInt(text.length() - i);  // get a random starting index


System.out.println(text.substring(index, index + i)); // print the substring
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
final Random random = new Random();
final int length = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int pos = random.nextInt(text.length() - length)
    System.out.println(text.substring(pos, pos + length));
}
```

As alternative to create substring, you can print separate characters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0, pos = random.nextInt(text.length() - length); j < length; j++)
        System.out.print(text.charAt(pos + j));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional variable to store the random value, i.e

```
String text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
Random random = new Random();

int i = 5, r;

for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    r = random.nextInt(text.length() - i)
    System.out.println(text.substring(r, r + i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the API `substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`. You need to pass `startIndex`  as a random number (`endIndex = startIndex + 5`). For more detail, you can refer [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

### Note:

Don't forget to check the value of startIndex. It can over your string length and throw an exception.